# How to prove that the 2 graph matrices describe the same graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

To simplify the question, we suppose that:

1. All verticles of $G$ are $v_1, v_2,...,v_n$
2. There is no edge which connect it with itself.
3. $G$ is non-directed.
4. There are at most one edge between 2 different verticles

Now, we focus on an $n\times n$ matrix $A=a_{ij}$. If $v_i$ and $v_j$ are connected, then $a_{ij}=a_{ji}=1$. If not, $a_{ij}=a_{ji}=0$.
It is obvious to konw that for the same graph G, the order of verticles are arbitrary, so if 2 graphs' matrix $A,B$ are given, how to know whether they are the same graph(isomorphic graph)?
Maybe it has some connection with $A=PAP^{-1}$ or something else?

------------------------------------------------------------------

Your comments are really helpful, thanks.
 2 year ago, when I first learned graph theory, the problem occured to me, since there are almost $\frac{n!}{2}$ possible situations to check if the 2 matrices are the "same", I guess it might be an NP problem.
And later, we learned something about abstract algebra. Graph isomorphism possibly has some connection with equivalent relationship, and by using it, we can classify the $n\times n$ matrices. So, maybe we can solve it by using algebra methods?

Comment: This is a very hard problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem

Comment: To clarify, $P$ is a permutation matrix? Essentially yes this is the right idea, if you already know that the two matrices can be derived from each other by permuting the order of the vertices, then yes they are the "same" graph in the sense you have in mind. That being said, as the previous comment points out, the naive/brute force approach of checking all possible permutations (i.e. if you don't already know what the specific permutation is) is extremely inefficient, and while there are improved algorithms, it is still a hard problem with no "great" solutions.

Comment: It's a hard problem with no great solutions for very symmetric graphs. Good algorithms work very well in the average case.

Answer (score 3):

The [Graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-exponential_time) is in NP (obviously), but is not known to be NP-complete. The best known result is that it is in the quasi-polynomial time (Babai).

Comment: Maybe algebra methods might not be helpful...  Algebra cannot tell us how to find the equivalent relationship, this is what computers can do. Thanks

Comment: @AntonLL: ?????

Comment: Babai algorithm can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03547).